# Сортировка по англ. алфавиту mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='u0415445_game' AND
    TABLE_NAME='users' AND
    COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id', 'nickname', 'steamid')
 ORDER BY ???
), ' FROM users');
```

Как отсортировать его (ORDER BY) по алфавиту?

Comment: просто clumn_name там пишите или по алфавиту в какой колонке вы отсортировать хотите. так же обратите внимание, что order by стоит указывать не в конце запроса, а внутри скобок group_concat (он это понимает)

Comment: Согласен с пользователем Mike. `ORDER BY` для того и создан, чтобы всё отсортировывать по/против алфавита :). Просто пропиши название столбца вместо `???`, и будет тебе счастье ;)